# Create a Django project following MVC pattern?

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

I am learning Django after moving from J2EE (Java). I have a problem with Django project layout following MVC pattern.
In J2EE, my project includes 3 main parts:

Model:

- JavaBean (DTO): defines classes based on Database tables.
- DAL: defines classes to manipulate java beans with database.

Controller:

- Servlets

View:

- JSP files

Therefore, I have 3 packages(DTO,DAL,Controller) and a folder containing JSP files.

I understand that Django uses MTV. However, there's a submodule of a Django project called "app" that contains "model" and "view" inside. This makes me confused when following project layout according to J2EE above.

Hope to receive some advises from you guys. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a project and an app, an app is a Web application that does something – e.g., a Weblog system, a database of public records or a simple poll app. A project is a collection of configuration and apps for a particular website. A project can contain multiple apps. An app can be in multiple projects.

Answer (score 0):

In django , a project is a container consists of multiple apps that each app has its own model view and controller.

for example your project can have **blog** and **news** apps.you can imagine that your java mvc application has been grouped to several apps.

go to each app's folder(you have named the first app , **app**) define your model in model.py and views...